# Which function satisfy $f'(\mathbb{N}) \subseteq \mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory, functions

I was thinking and found the following question :
Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function and consider the restrictions $f|_\mathbb{N}$ and $f'_\mathbb{N}$

i) Which functions satisfies $f(\mathbb{N}) \subseteq \mathbb{N}$?

ii) Which functions satisfies $f'(\mathbb{N}) \subseteq \mathbb{N}$?

Examples :

$f(x) = 2x$ satisfies i) and ii)

$g(x)=\frac{\sin(2\pi x)}{2\pi}$ satisfies just ii)

Comment: Oh sorry almost forget it

Comment: Are you trying to classify all such functions?

Comment: Yes I want i think is very interest question

Comment: a lot of functions satisfy that, since $\mathbb N$ is not dense we have a ton of continuous extensions for any function $f:\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$ to all of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I'm skeptical that a simple classification exists, since there are a lot of continuous functions *alone* intersect lattice points, since intuitively speaking, there is enough "space" in between each natural number [Real numbers are not in the closure of the natural numbers]

Comment: I agree with you there are a lot. But not all functions when we extend satisfy for example $f'(\mathbb{N}) \subset \mathbb{N}$. Exists necessary conditions to classify them. Are more continuous functions than functions above?.

Comment: The set of continuous functions from $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{R}$ and the subsets of that set of functions that you have described above all have the same cardinality as $\Bbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **very partial answer**.  We can classify all **polynomials** with property (i), **provided** you are willing to replace $\Bbb N$ by $\def\Z{{\Bbb Z}}\Z$.

**Lemma**.  Any polynomial with real coefficients can be written in the form
$$f(x)=a_0+a_1\binom x1+a_2\binom x2+\cdots+a_n\binom xn\ ,$$
where
$$\binom xk=\frac{x(x-1)\cdots(x-(k-1))}{k!}\ .$$

**Proof**.  Clear, because $\binom xk$ has degree $k$.

**Theorem**.  If $f$ is written as above, then
$$f(\Z)\subseteq\Z\quad\hbox{if and only if}\quad\hbox{all $a_k$ are integers}.$$

**Proof**.  "If" is clear.  Conversely, suppose $f(\Z)\subseteq\Z$.  Then
$$a_0=f(0)\in\Z\ .$$
Also, for every $x\in\Z$ we have $f(x+1)-f(x)\in\Z$.  Manipulating the sum gives
$$f(x+1)-f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{k+1}\binom xk\ ;$$
since this is a polynomial of degree $n-1$, we can conclude by induction that $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ are integers.

I have omitted a couple of details, will leave them up to you.